# Automatically add subtitles to a youtube video

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I want to embed a youtube video on my website. The original video is not in english and I want that for people visiting my website, the video shows up with the subtitles in english. I know how to do this for myself, but how can I do this for all visitors automatically?

Answer (score 3):

In the embed code (which I assume is an iframe) just add cc_load_policy=1 after the url. So like this:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/randomvideo-VE?cc_load_policy=1" frameborder="0"/>
```

This should automatically enable captions, even if users have it disabled by default.

Source: [Youtube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en)

To specify a language, use the `&hl=es&cc_lang_pref=langID` parameter before the `?cc_load_policy`.
langID: es for spanish, en for english, etc.

Source: [Force Closed Captions in YT videos](http://www.captionsforyoutube.com/blog/posts/10-how-to-force-closed-captions-to-appear-on-your-youtube-videos)

Comment: and which option to add them in a specific language?

Comment: @flow edited my post.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.